# How to configure Spark spark_worker_opts for Jupyter notebooks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I use Pyspark with Spark 2.4 in the standalone mode on Linux for processing a lot of incoming data via Kafka using a Jupyter notebook (currently for testing). I want to add these options to this notebook in order to prevent the /tmp/ directory to be filled with dozens of gigabytes after few hours:

```
spark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true
spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=120
```

But these conf locations do not work:

1. Spark’s default configuration (spark/conf/spark-env.sh) seems not be used by Juypter notebooks at all:

> SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="spark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true
> spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=120"

2. So, I created a sperate kernel configuration in ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3-spark1/kernel.json that I can select in Jupyterhub and that is really used for the RAM adjustments what I can see in htop:

> "env": {
> "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local[*]
> --conf spark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true --conf=spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=120 driver-memory 145g --executor-memory 50g pyspark-shell"

but the /tmp still fills with dozens of gigs.

3. I also tried the “magic” in a jupyter cell but it also did not work.

Do you know how to configure the Jupyter notebooks for this Spark adjustments properly?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration properties that apply only to the worker in the form `"-Dx=y"`

```
export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="$SPARK_WORKER_OPTS -Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=60 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=120"
```

If that not work you can try any of the below options.

**Option-1:** Updating default.conf

In Worker node set the following configuration option in the `/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` file:

- `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled`: Enables periodic cleanup of worker and application directories. Disabled by default. Set to true to enable it. **Note:** that this only affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.interval`: The frequency, in seconds, that the worker cleans up old application work directories. The default is 30 minutes.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl:` The number of seconds to retain application work directories on each worker. The default is 7 days.

Then stop and start the workers.

- `sbin/stop-worker.sh` - Stops all worker instances on the machine the script is executed on.
- `sbin/start-worker.sh` - Starts a worker instance on the machine the script is executed on.

**Option-2:** If you setup a spark cluster using docker-compose then set environment in Docker compose file

```
spark-worker-x:
    image: spark-worker
    container_name: spark-worker-x
    environment:
      - SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=60 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=120"
```